# Convert docx to xml

Tags: xml, openxml, office-2007

I have a Microsoft Office 2007(docx) word document. I want to convert this to Structured XML format. So that I can read the data and put it in Database easily based on the xml element and attribute name.

How can I easily achieve? If I can convert the word to open xml format how can I read the open xml because it is not easy to fetch the open xml format data.

Comment: Please leave off stuff like "Please help me in this." The fact that you posted a question implies you want us to help. Anything more sounds like begging.

Answer (score 7):

You can easily convert docx files to xml by -

1- open terminal

2- cd to the location of the word document

`cd path/to/your/file.docx`

3- run command

`unzip file.docx -d folder-name`

Comment: just to complement, it becomes unformatted, to format all the xml files from the folder I did this script:

`find open-xml-outputs -type f -name "*.xml" -exec xmllint --format {} -o {}.formatted \; -exec mv {}.formatted {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

A docx is composed of multiple xml files. You would have to come up with your own way to disassemble and reassemble the components into a single docx. It would be possible to create a database structure representative of the docx structure. Unless you need to access and modify the word document programmatically, I would say that it is not advisable to replicate the structure directly. It makes more sense to create a solution tailored to your application. If you just want to store docx files, consider just storing them directly rather than disassembling them.